# jQuery UI tabs panelTemplate option deprecated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.10

So I upgraded jquery ui from 1.8 to 1.10.
Tabs seem to have been refactored in 1.9 already according to this: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9

While reading through - this came up:

> Deprecated idPrefix, tabTemplate, and panelTemplate options; use
>   refresh method
>
> As mentioned above, the add and remove methods have been deprecated.
>   As a result, the idPrefix, tabTemplate, and panelTemplate options have
>   been deprecated as well. You should replace all uses of the idPrefix,
>   tabTemplate, and panelTemplate options with the markup you would like
>   to use.

Not very clear what `You should replace all uses... with the markup you would like to use` means.

HTML

```
<div id="main-xxx-tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.php">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.php">link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery("#main-xxx-tabs").tabs({
  panelTemplate: "<div class='main-xxx-tabs-content'></div>"
})
```

If anyone could provide an example of how to upgrade this properly - would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI 1.8 had the `add` and `remove` methods (and associated events) which served the purpose of dynamically removing or adding tabs to your widget.

From the [legacy 1.8 documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/) for `tabs`:

> - **add( url, label [, index ] )**
>     Add a tab.
>
>   ---
> - **remove( index )**
>     Remove a tab.

The two methods used the following options:

> **panelTemplate** *Type: String*
>
> ---
>
> Default: ""
>   HTML template from which a new tab panel is created in case of adding a tab with the add() method or when creating a panel for a remote tab on the fly.
>
> **tabTemplate** *Type: String*
>
> ---
>
> [[see doc]](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#option-tabTemplate)
>
> **idPrefix** *Type: String*
>
> ---
>
> [[see doc]](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#option-idPrefix)

As you can see `panelTemplate` is the HTML template which the panel is created from using the `add` method.

All of this is now deprecated - the current method of adding or removing tabs dynamically is with the assistance of the new `refresh` method:

> **refresh()**
>
> ---
>
> Process any tabs that were added or removed directly in the DOM and recompute the height of the tab panels. Results depend on the content and the heightStyle option.
>   This method does not accept any arguments.

As the upgrade guide states, you need to remove all `add` and `remove` method calls in your script, replacing them with code that directly manipulates the DOM, and then calling `refresh()`.
Additionally, you need to discard any set options of `idPrefix`, `tabTemplate`, and `panelTemplate`.

As your code suggests, somewhere down the line you are using the `add` method, for example:

```
$("#main-xxx-tabs").tabs("add", "/remote/tab.html", "New Tab");
```

With the new `tabs` API, you should do something similar to (taking into account your current `panelTemplate` value):

```
/* Add tab */
$("#main-xxx-tabs .ui-tabs-nav")
   .append("<li aria-controls='newTabID1'><a href='/remote/tab.html'>New Tab</a></li>")

/* Add respective tab panel (content) and refresh widget */
$("#main-xxx-tabs")
   .append("<div id="newTabID1" class='main-xxx-tabs-content'>New Tab Content</div>");
   .tabs("refresh");
```

This would create a new tab. You can replace the value of `href` to be the same as `aria-controls` \ `id` if you do not need a remote loading (ajax) tab.

Finally, the upgrade guide also gives you an example of [how to remove a tab with the new API](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method).

#### Edit:

---

In case you were just using `panelTemplate` as a template for your primary (first) tabs, as opposed to dynamically creating them, then the same rules apply; you will have to directly add the appropriate html. If your html before the upgrade was:

```
<div id="main-xxx-tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="link1.php">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.php">link2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then you should do something along the lines of:

```
<div id="main-xxx-tabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
      <li><a href="link1.php">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="link2.php">link2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <!-- vv Constructed from your original panelTemplate vv -->
   <div id="tabs-1" class="main-xxx-tabs-content">
      <p>Your preloaded content here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And to further clarify, a `panel` is the content div for your tab.
For ajax-loaded tabs, you do not need to create a panel - it will be automatically created for you.

So effectively, to get things going again, you just have to remove the `panelTemplate` option.
Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating ajax-loaded, as well as preloaded tabs:
http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/LWmVv/
See also the [jQuery UI Tabs Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax).

Comment: Not sure I follow - I do not wish to add more tabs, just somehow set the template for all the tabs. Content for those tabs is loaded through ajax.

Comment: You should read the jQuery UI Tabs documentation, it is all laid out for you. However I expanded my answer to include some more examples and to further explain the differences.